# Upload image to folder with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app to let a user upload a picture. I want to be able to save that picture into a folder. However, the console returns an error. The path is correct, so I am not sure what am I missing:

Error:

```
/c/UOMDataAnalytics/MINSTP201902DATA4/Homework/VisualizePictures/OldPortsApp/static/Images/uploads/WIN_20140917_095804.JPG
```

Flask code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template,make_response,url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

UploadDir="/Images/uploads/"

# image upload route
@app.route("/upload-image", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_image():
    app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"] = UploadDir

    # print (app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"])
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            image = request.files["image"]
            image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename))        
            print(image.filename)
            return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template("public/upload_image.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I would expect to see the uploaded picture on the upload directory. I want to deploy this to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue with path. just try to replace this line

```
image.save(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__),'..', UploadDir, image.filename)).
```

I think It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked fine for me!

`picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, '/Images/uploads/', image.filename)`
`image.save(picture_path)`